# WPF Binding list of strings to Label as simple as possible

Tags: c#, wpf

My object has property like this:

```
public List<String> Names{ get; set; }
```

Assume my Names list has 3 names.

I would like to bind that property to a `Label` in WPF so it shows the names like:

**name1, name2, name3**

I am binding like this currently but that displays nothing:

```
<Label Name="lblNames" Content="{Binding Names}"/>
```

Comment: A textbox? That implies two-way binding. What do you want to happen if a user edits the contents of the textbox?

Comment: that text box is not editable.  Imaging it were just a Label.  Thanks

Comment: Just use value converters. Take the list. Check if it is null or not if not then use string.join(",", list.ToArray() )

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of solutions here:

1. (Simple) Create an additional computed property on your ViewModel object to expose the list as a comma separated list: `public string NameList { get { return string.Join(", ", this.Names); } }`
2. (harder) Create a [ValueConverter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) that joins the elements in your list; and bind to your list.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a IvalueConverter

```
    internal class ListToString : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is List<string>)
            {
                return string.Join(", ", value);
            }

            return null;
        }  


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and in XAML

```
<Label Name="lblNames" Content="{Binding Names,Converter={StaticResource ListToString}}"/>
```